# Как узнать скорость выполнения запроса MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Как можно получить количество миллисекунд для запроса?

Читал, что есть функция `Explain`, но она не выводит время запроса.

Так будет нормально?

```
$startTime = microtime();
ЗАПРОС
$endTime = microtime();
```

Comment: Правильно заданный вопрос - это уже половина ответа? ))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В MySQL > 5.0.37 есть встроенный профайлер. Его можно включить вот так:

```
set profiling=1;
select count(*) from comment;
select count(*) from message;
show profiles;
```

В результате получим:

```
+----------+------------+------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                        |
+----------+------------+------------------------------+
|        1 | 0.00012700 | select count(*) from comment |
|        2 | 0.00014200 | select count(*) from message |
+----------+------------+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Так можно отследить "честное" время выполнения запроса, минуя время на коннект с MySQL :)

Вот собственно [сабж](http://habrahabr.ru/post/70435/)

Comment: А страница-то не найдена))

От себя добавлю, что для получения информации о конкретном запросе следует использовать

    show profile for query 1;

Таким образом можно увидеть что в запросе тормозит.

[Первоисточник](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-profiles.html)

Comment: Спасибо получилось.

Comment: @BOPOH а мне кажется что найдена :)

Comment: Видно у хабра какие-то проблемы были, сейчас и у меня найдена)